# Python voice assistant acces denied error

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I'm doing a voice assistant with python, but I get the error [in this picture](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/804352407370334239/847388460423315497/unknown.png), I put the file name randomly, again nothing has changed, how do I solve it.I can only communicate once

Comment: Hello @Seyyid Ahmed Topbaş welcome to SO! please add code and dont add image you can paste your error, so it will be better for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
from playsound import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr
import os as pc
import time as saat 
from datetime import date, datetime
import random
from random import choice

r = sr.Recognizer()

def record(ask = False):
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        if ask:
            print(ask)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        voice = ""
        try:
            voice = r.recognize_google(audio, language="tr-TR")
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Asistan: Anlayamadım")
            speak("anlayamadım")
        except sr.RequestError:
            print("Asistan: Sistem çalışmıyor")
            speak("Sistem çalışmıyor")
        return voice

def response(voice):
    if "merhaba" in voice:
        speak("sanada merhaba")
    if "selam" in voice:
        speak("selam")
    if "teşekkür ederim" in voice or "teşekkürler" in voice:
        speak("rica ederim")
    if "görüşürüz" in voice or "bay bay" in voice:
        speak("görüşürüz")
        exit()
    if "hangi gündeyiz" in voice or "hangi gün" in voice or "bugün hangi gün":
        today = saat.strftime("%A")
        today.capitalize()
        if today == "Monday":
            today = "Pazartesi"

        elif today == "Tuesday":
            today = "Salı"

        elif today == "Wednesday":
            today = "Çarşamba"

        elif today == "Thursday":
            today = "Perşembe"

        elif today == "Friday":
            today = "Cuma"

        elif today == "Saturday":
            today = "Cumartesi"

        elif today == "Sunday":
            today = "Pazar"

        speak(today)

    if "saat kaç" in voice or "şuan saat kaç" in voice:
        selection = ["Saat şu an: ", "Hemen bakıyorum: "]
        clock = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        selection = random.choice(selection)
        speak(selection + clock)

ad = random.randint(0,9)
adil = str(ad)
def speak(string):
    tts = gTTS(text=string, lang="tr", slow=False)
    file = adil + '.mp3'
    tts.save(file)
    playsound(file)
    pc.remove(file)

playsound('DING.mp3')
while True:
    voice = record()
    if voice != '':
        voice = voice.lower()
        print(voice.capitalize())
        response(voice)
```

Comment: Heey Seyyid, Is this part of your answer or question, if it belongs to your question, it's best to edit this code in your question. Now it seems confusing to other people, because they might take this as an answer to your question.